# SpringBoot project failing to connect to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I'm trying to execute a SpringBoot project, however I'm having this problem running:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/aiko
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

[image]

I tried some codes read on forums but it didn't work

Comment: What dependencies do you have for spring boot? Are you using SpringBootApplication annotation in the main class?

Comment: Is your application.properties file located in the resources folder?

Comment: Can you remove this line `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver` and try? Works for me in my local with Spring boot version 2.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can add these dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Why do you want to add an h2 DB dependency when there is already a data source in Postgres? The question is asked on Postgres.

Answer (score -1):

Solved with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

in pom.xml archive